# How does Windows 10 source drivers for network printers?

Tags: windows-10, printer, network-printer, print-drivers

We have a Konica Minolta 4695mf on a local domain network.  No printers added by GPO or scripts at this time.  I have removed all printer shares from PCs, so I am reasonably certain that its only exposure is the device itself.  In the Windows 10 GUI, when I choose 'Add a printer or scanner', the 4695mf's name pops up and I can install it without trouble.  Print Management shows that its driver date is 2013.  There are more recent drivers on the Konica website, presented as just INF files.  Question : When Windows 10 adds the printer driver, where is it sourcing the driver?  Is it downloading from the printer itself, a Microsoft repository,  Konica (unlikely), or the domain controller?  The DC doesn't have the 4695mf driver loaded in Print Management.

Comment: Windows 8 changed the way printer drivers worked.  This feature carried over into Windows 10.  The printer driver model changed in numerous ways with the release of Windows 8.

Comment: Thanks.  Any resources I can use to get a clear picture?  Googling yields a lot of noise thus far.